# How can I extract month name and quarter from a date in Excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to take date information from cell A1 (e.g. 10/10/2013 09:00) and transfer the month into cell B1 (October) and then based on the month fill in cell C1 the proper quarter (Q4). How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: When does Q1 begin? If that's 1st Jan then October would be Q4

Comment: correct it would be Q4, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the month from A1, simply do, at B1

```
=(A1)
```

To get the quarter of A1, based on B1, I like to use this formula on C1:

```
=INT((B1-1)/3)+1
```

If you want a column that shows month names, use the following formula (you may have to use `,` instead of `;`:

```
=TEXT(A1;"mmm")
```

One problem with this approach is that you can't use this formula on `B1`, or else the formula on `C1` won't work. That is, unless you bypass B1 and have C1 referr directly to A1, like this:

```
=INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)+1
```